# How to find the months in a year using Ruby

Tags: ruby

How to find the months in a year till this month.

`months_of_year` should return (2013-01-01, 2013-02-01, 2013-03-01, 2013-04-01, 2013-05-01) (assuming current month is 2013-05-01)

Comment: Are you using Rails or Ruby?

Comment: @limelights, correct me if I'm wrong, but is this possible to use Rails without Ruby?

Comment: Exactly. The question was "using ROR". Just fishing for clarification but it was apparently to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create helper method:

```
def months_of_year(till = Date.today)
  (1..till.month).map { |m| Date.new(till.year, m) }
end
```

This will return array of dates of each 1st days from the beginning of year.

Comment: Great ! Its working for me ! Thank u so much for quick response !

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an array of beginning of month dates for this year until today.

```
i=Date.today.beginning_of_year
a = []
while i <= Date.today
  a << i.beginning_of_month
  i=i + 1.month
end
```

Comment: Don't you think that this is a little bit too bloated? And also it isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
require "date"
require "time"
(1..DateTime.now.month).map{|i| Date.new(DateTime.now.year,i,1).to_s }
#=> ["2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-01", "2013-05-01"]
```

Comment: There is no need to use `DateTime`.